# How do I double timeval in C?

Tags: c, time.h, timeval

I am very new to C and I have the following code where I want to double the timeval, how can I do this?

```
#include <time.h>

struct timeval t ={1, 10000}; 

while(1){
    //some code to use timeval 
    Here I need to double the timeval. Meaning if the timeval was 1.1 seconds, I need to make t = 2.2
    seconds. 
}
```

Comment: The double of `1.1` is `2.2`, not `2.1`. Nitpicking aside, what have you tried? How did your attempt work or not work?

Comment: I will fix that on the question. I tried to just double the microseconds but turns out it crashes after a while probably because it reaches long limit. It is not the best way to do it for sure.

Comment: Show us what you did that crashed.  You should not be running into overflow problems.

Comment: `1, 10000` would be 1.1 seconds if the 2nd member was a count of 1/100,000 of a second.  Certainly OP wanted `1, 100000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double *both* the microseconds and the seconds.

Then you need to check for overflow of the microseconds (if it's larger than one million) in which case you need to add another second and subtract one "second" from the microseconds.